# Valid transition function for a markov chain in a bayesian posterior distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains, bayesian, monte-carlo

Given a posterior distribution $\pi(\theta|X)$, we would like it to support the real line $\mathbb{R}$ through MCMC(Markov chain Monte Carlo).
For a given function,I would like to find out whether it is a valid transition function for a Markov Chain that converges to the posterior distribution(i.e,converges to $\pi(\theta|X)$).
Let $\begin{equation}
    \theta^{(t)}=
   \begin{cases}
   \theta^{t-1}&\mbox{with prob = r}\\
   \theta^{'}&\mbox{with prob = 1-r}
   \end{cases}
  \end{equation}  $
Where $\theta^{'} \sim \theta^{t-1} + N(0,1)$

and $r = min(1,\frac{\pi(\theta^{(t-1)}|X)}{\pi(\theta^{'}|X)})$.

I have no idea where to start.Is there any property that this function need to satisfy to converge to the posterior?
Thanks in advance.